# In my house, "there were" or "there was" many toys

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, american-english, verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct and why:

1) In my house, there **were** many toys.

2) In my house, there **was** many toys.

An answer with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Many toys_ is plural, so you would use a plural verb.

Comment: Take a hint: Were (plural verb) and Was (singular verb). So, for plural noun (many toys) which one you will use?

Comment: Exam questions may be off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Answer #1 is correct; use the plural verb, **were**, because there are multiple toys.

> In my house, there **were** many toys.

If you were talking about 1 pile of toys though, you would use "**was**," the singular verb, because there is 1, single pile. For example:

> "There **was** a pile of toys on the living room floor!"

See this website for more help on the topic: https://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference

Best wishes!

Comment: But not 'There was a dozen toys ...'.